# Logging out threads in VBS

Tags: vba, vbscript

```
cmd = "ipconfig"
Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
outfile = fso.GetTempName
sh.Run "%COMSPEC% /c " & cmd & " 2>" & outfile & _
    " 1>" & outfile, 0, true
```

I have fragment of VBS code when I execute command "*ipconfig*". I want get all information from data and error threads in the same .tmp file.
But after executing this code .tmp file is empty.
So I can't understand why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this way :

```
cmd = "ipconfig"
Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
outfile = fso.GetTempName
sh.Run "%COMSPEC% /C " & cmd & ">" & outfile & " 2>&1", 0, true
sh.Run "Notepad " & outfile
```

**Edit : other code to test**

```
cmd = "Taskkill /F /IM iexplore.exe"
Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
outfile = fso.GetTempName
sh.Run "%COMSPEC% /C " & cmd & ">" & outfile & " 2>&1", 0, true
sh.Run "Notepad " & outfile
```

Comment: @BondarAnton for me it's works 5/5 ! under Windows 7
Check my last edit

Comment: cmd = "Taskkill /F /IM iexplore.exe" - nice joke !

Comment: @BondarAnton :  Did you mean is still didn't work ? please explain more what did you mean ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create or overwrite a TXT file to pipe the output to then use a single `>` greater than symbol.

```
sh.Run "%COMSPEC% /c " & cmd & " 2>" & outfile & " 1>" & outfile, 0, true
```

If you want to append the piped output to an existing file (or create a new one) then use two `>>` greater than symbols.

```
sh.Run "%COMSPEC% /c " & cmd & " 2>>" & outfile & " 1>>" & outfile, 0, true
```